# python NoneType object is not iterable

Tags: python, types, typeerror, iterable, nonetype

This code runs fine when "filename" is a file that exists... when it doesn't, however...
I keep getting the same error: 
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable (Errno 2)

Even though i never iterate on anything unless a file is opened at the very start of the function. I've looked over my code many times over and can not find where i would iterate on an object that is not iterable.

NB. I've also tried with "except IOError" and I get the same result.

The function takes only one argument, its the variable "filename"

Taceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Saume\Workspace\Chess\src\Main.py", line 431, in <module>
   game1, board1 = loadgame(inp_f)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

NB. the call to the function is done with a string that is collected from user input "inp_f" (loadgame is the name of the function)

Here's the code:

```
try: 
    f = open(filename, "r")
    file_empty = False
except FileNotFoundError: 
    file_empty = True
    # file doesn't exist, error string

if file_empty: # empty save file, create a new game
    g, b = creategame() # this function works 100%... no problems here
else: 
    # amount of each pieces
    tb = 0
    tn = 0
    cb = 0
    cn = 0
    fb = 0
    fn = 0
    db = 0
    dn = 0
    rb = 0
    rn = 0
    pb = 0
    pn = 0

    d = {} # dictionnary for the board

    n = 0
    f_game = ""
    f_pieces = []
    for line in f: # iterate on the file... only if file_empty == False....
        if n == 0: # first line contains general game info
            f_game = line
        else: # other lines contain coordinates of the pieces
            f_pieces += [line]
        n += 1 # increment number of lines... n-1 == number of pieces

    f.close() # close the file... only if the file was opened...

    # validating the format of the first line
    try: 
        temp1 = int(f_game[0])
        temp2 = int(f_game[2])
        temp3 = int(f_game[4])
        temp4 = int(f_game[6])
        temp5 = int(f_game[8])
        f_game = [temp1, None, temp2, None, temp3, None, temp4, None, temp5]
    except ValueError: 
        pass # display error message... bad format


    for i in f_pieces: # iterate on the list that contains information about pieces
        try: 
            i1 = int(i[0])
            i2 = int(i[1])
        except ValueError: # bad coordinates... piece is put outside the board
            i1 = 8
            i2 = 8
        if i[2] == "T": # rook
            if i[3] == "B": # white

                if f_game[2] != 0 and i1 == 0 and i2 == 7: # short white roc is possible... this is the right rook, too
                    did_first_move = False
                elif f_game[4] != 0 and i1 == 0 and i2 == 0: # long white roc is possible... and this is the right rook, too
                    did_first_move = False
                else:  # it is not one a rook implied ina  possible roc
                    did_first_move = True

                tb += 1 # increment the amount of this piece by 1

                globals()["tb" + str(tb)] = Rook.Rook(0, i1, i2, did_first_move) # from the import Rook... which contains class Rook with its initializer that takes 4 args (color, line, column, first_move)
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["tb" + str(tb)] # add it to the board dictionary... key is a tuple... element is a Piece.Piece class

            else: # black...Rook still

                if f_game[6] != 0 and i1 == 7 and i2 == 7: # short black roc possible... this is the right rook, too
                    did_first_move = False
                elif f_game[8] != 0 and i1 == 7 and i2 == 0: # long black roc possible... this is the right rook, too
                    did_first_move = False
                else:  # the rook is not implied in a possible roc
                    did_first_move = True

                tn += 1 # increment piece type

                globals()["tn" + str(tn)] = Rook.Rook(1, i1, i2, did_first_move) # once again... from the import that takes 4 args

                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["tn" + str(tn)] # put it in the board dictionary

        elif i[2] == "C": # Knight
            if i[3] == "B": # white

                cb += 1 # increment
                globals()["cb" + str(cb)] = Knight.Knight(0, i1, i2) # from the import... not it takes 3 or 4 args... the last one being optional... as wether a Knight did their first move of not is irrelevant... it is not needed to pass a 4th arg
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["cb" + str(cb)] # put it in the board dictionary

            else: # black
                cn += 1 # increment
                globals()["cn" + str(cn)] = Knight.Knight(1, i1, i2) # create class instance from import...
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["cn" + str(cn)] # put it in the board dictionary

        elif i[2] == "F": # Bishop
            if i[3] == "B": # white

                fb += 1 # increment
                globals()["fb" + str(fb)] = Bishop.Bishop(0, i1, i2) # create class instance from import...
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["fb" + str(fb)] # put it in the board dictionary

            else: # black

                fn += 1 # increment
                globals()["fn" + str(fn)] = Fou.Fou(1, i1, i2) # create class instance from import...
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["fn" + str(fn)] # put it inside the board dictionary

        elif i[2] == "D": # Queen
            if i[3] == "B": # white

                db += 1 # increment
                globals()["db" + str(db)] = Queen.Queen(0, i1, i2) # create class instance from import...
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["db" + str(db)] # put it in the board dictionary

            else: # black

                dn += 1 # increment
                globals()["dn" + str(dn)] = Queen.Queen(1, i1, i2) # create class instance from import...
                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["dn" + str(dn)] # put it inside the board dictionary

        elif i[2] == "R": # King
            if i[3] == "B": # white

                if f_game[2] != 0 or f_game[4] != 0: # white king did not perform its first move
                    did_first_move = False
                else:  # white king did move
                    did_first_move = True

                rb += 1 # increment

                globals()["rb" + str(rb)] = King.King(0, i1, i2, did_first_move) # create class instance from the import...

                pos_r0 = (i1, i2)

                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["rb" + str(rb)] # put it inside the board dictionary

            else: # black

                if f_game[6] != 0 or f_game[8] != 0: # black king did not perform its first move
                    did_first_move = False
                else:  # black king did move
                    first = True

                rn += 1 # increment

                globals()["rn" + str(rn)] = King.King(1, i1, i2, did_first_move) # create class instance from import...

                pos_r1 = (i1, i2)

                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if the coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["rn" + str(rn)] # put it in the board dictionary

        else: # pawn
            if i[3] == "B": # white

                if i1 == 1: # the pawn is still at its starting position
                    did_first_move = False
                else: # the pawn moved from its starting position
                    did_first_move = True

                pb += 1 # increment

                globals()["pb" + str(pb)] = Pawn.Pawn(0, i1, i2, did_first_move) # create class instance from import

                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["pb" + str(pb)] # put it in the board dictionary

            else: # black

                if i1 == 1: # the pawn is still at its starting position
                    did_first_move = False
                else: # the pawn moved from its starting position
                    did_first_move = True

                pn += 1 # increment

                globals()["pn" + str(pn)] = Pawn.Pawn(0, i1, i2, prem_depl) # create class instance from import...

                if i1 < 8 and i2 < 8: # if coordinates are valid...
                    d[(i1, i2)] = globals()["pn" + str(pn)] # put it in the board dictionary

    # create the board class instance from import... which only takes 1 arg... the board itself (dict)
    b = Board.Board(d)

    # create the game (GameManagement class instance... from import)
    # it takes 3 optional args... number of turns since the start of the game, position of white king and position of black king...
    g = GameManagement.GameManagement(f_game[0], pos_r0, pos_r1)

    return g, b
```

Edit: Hah. Thanks a lot, i was so stuck on the iteration error i did not even find this when i spent over an hour looking over everything that could cause an iteration error.

It was just the return statement's identation.

Comment: Could you add the traceback? As a hunch what does `creategame()` return?

Comment: Posting a huge mountain of code is not a good idea. Can you please identify where (which line) the error occurs ?

Comment: Can you check whether the `except FileNotFoundError` is actually called? And I don't think it's `FileNotFoundError`, it should be `IOError`. Try change that and add a print statement inside to see whether the exception is called.

Comment: And apparently the error is on the last line, haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would guess that the problem is on the last line, is should be dedented (reduce the indentation by one level). In your current code, when the file is not found, the function will return `None`. And your `NoneType` error might occur on the code using the output of this function.

Try reduce the indentation of your return statement.

EDIT:

Seeing your traceback, this issue is confirmed to be the error, as it can't unpack `None` into `game1` and `board1`

Answer (score 2):

The indentation of the return statement

```
return g,b
```

makes it a part of the `else` in you function. If the file cannot be opened, you create a new game

```
g,b = creategame()
```

but never *return* it. So maybe the code that consumes the values returned by this function raises the error.  You should de-indent (if there's such a word) the `return` statement to make it a part of the function code and not the `else` branch

Or maybe the `creategame()` returns None and your line `g,b = creategame()` raises the error.

For such questions posting (and analyzing) the traceback will help you debug the code faster.

Comment: I'm a bit faster than you =p